# Nginx in chroot jail, symlink to available servers not working

Tags: arch-linux, webserver, nginx

I've set up Nginx inside a chroot jail at `/srv/http` (Arch Linux). I've modified my `nginx.conf` so that it includes my enabled servers:

```
include /etc/nginx/servers-enabled/*;
```

And I've symlinked the files in `servers-enabled` to `servers-available`. Although the `disable_symlinks` is off by default, I've made sure it is really off by adding `disable_symlinks off;` to `nginx.conf`. However, after reloading nginx, I cannot reach the website.

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715871/nginx-not-picking-up-site-in-sites-enabled) and made sure that I used absolute paths. However, I'm not sure if nginx can access the path because it is (partially) outside of the chroot jail.

So I tried the following:

```
cd /srv/http
ln -s etc/nginx/servers-available/example etc/nginx/servers-enabled/example
```

So now I use relative paths, but at least inside the chroot jail. Unfortunately, also with this setup I cannot reach the website.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So relative paths do seem to work with symlink inside the chroot.

Here is the code that I used

```
cd /srv/http/etc/nginx/servers-enabled
ln -s ../servers-available/example example
```